# Labeling Legs in a Loop on a graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to make a graph with some loops such as this one,

```
GraphPlot[{{2 -> -2, "a"}, {-2 -> 2, "b"}, {2 -> 6, "b"}, {6 -> 8, "b"}, {8 -> 10, "b"}, {10 -> 8, "c"}}]
```

Where the output is [image: Mathematica Output]

In my GraphPlot function, I have 2 -> -2 labeled as "a" and -2 -> 2 as "b". Instead, Mathematica chooses the first instance and gives the other leg in the loop the same label. So for example, if I were to switch the ordering {2 -> -2,"a"} and {-2 -> 2,"b"} that loop would be labeled as "b,b" instead of "a,a". Any suggestions on how to make the loop labeled as "a,b" would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you have a version before v12, `GraphPlot` works better (you get the desired/expected output).

Comment: Ya, unfortunately, I updated to v12 and I am thinking about reverting back now.

Comment: do you have multi-edges in your edge list?

Comment: I ended up taking your original suggestion and reverted back to 11.3 and this solved all of the issues I was having with GraphPlot. Thanks for the info.

Comment: user5277691, please see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
GraphPlot[{{2 -> -2, "a"}, {-2 -> 2, "b"}, {2 -> 6, "b"}, {6 -> 8, 
   "b"}, {8 -> 10, "b"}, {10 -> 8, "c"}}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Re *"reverted back to 11.3 and this solved all of the issues I was having with GraphPlot."*

Losing quiet a few convenient features (including -- unlike `Graph` -- handling labeling of multi-edges correctly) with the v12 update to `GraphPlot` probably dismayed many users and WRI must have anticipated that.  Following the hunch that the old `GraphPlot` can not possibly be completely inaccessible in v12, a simple search revealed **`` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy ``**.

Hence no need to down-grade to v11 to be able to use the legacy `GraphPlot` and no need to look for work-arounds to replicate the legacy functionality ... just use `` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy ``:

```
GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy[{{2 -> -2, "a"}, {-2 -> 2, "b"}, {2 -> 6, "b"}, 
   {6 -> 8, "b"}, {8 -> 10, "b"}, {10 -> 8, "c"}},
  MultiedgeStyle -> 1/2, BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

With multi-edges

```
GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy[{{2 -> -2, "a"}, {2 -> - 2,  "b"},
    {2 -> - 2, "c"}, {2 -> 6, "b"}, {6 -> 8, "b"}, {8 -> 10, "w"},
    {8 -> 10, "x"}, {8 -> 10, "y"}, {8 -> 10, "z"}}, 
   MultiedgeStyle -> 1/2, BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

If you don't have multi-edges, you can replace `->` with `\[DirectedEdge]` in your edge list (or use the option `DirectedEdges->True` as in halmir's answer) and add the option `EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[0]`:

```
el = {{2 -> -2, "a"}, {-2 -> 2, "b"}, {2 -> 6, "b"}, {6 -> 8, "b"},
   {8 -> 10, "b"}, {10 -> 8, "c"}}/. Rule -> DirectedEdge;

GraphPlot[el, EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[0]]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, thanks for the info this is also super helpful.